# Неверно отображает описание сайта (Description)

Tags: html

Проблема такова: в гугле неверно отображает описание товара, парсит название из слайдера (который имеется на сайте), Description, который я задал - не хочет выдавать, будто бы что-то его перебивает главнее, хотя, понятия не имею, что?

```
<meta name = "Description" content="Пример 123 блабла" />
```

Слайдер:

```
<div class="hSright">
                            <div class="hSrBg">
                                <div class="sliderTexting">
                                    <div class="sTitle">Название товара</div>
                                    Решив <strong> тестануть страницу</strong> Отображается данное описание <br /> В гугле!<br /> Что делать?
                                    <br /><a href="http://google.com/" class="globBtn">Перейти к сайту</a>
```

В яндексе отображает корректное описание сайта.
Кэш обновлен.
Страницы должны быть тоже в гугле обновлены.

Comment: Возможно, из-за strong?

Comment: Или я запутался в разметке? Выделил бы код хотя бы :)

Comment: Гуглу начхать в большинстве случаев на мета тэг Description, если описание не соответствует контенту.

Comment: @kzcool, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `strong` попробуйте написать

```
<span class="bold"></span>

.bold {
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Суровая реальность такова: из-за того, что этот мета-тэг нещадно эксплуатировали все чёрные сеошники, пауки перестали на него внимание особое обращать, анализируется сам текст.
Из-за этого поведения некоторые даже советуют забить на `Description`, хотя это, конечно же, неправильно - вес он всё же имеет, а если контент будет соответствовать описанию, то паук будет в будущем больше ему доверять, а может и брать чистое описание оттуда. Если сильно подружатся :)

P. S. Тэги нещадно вырезаются пауками, так что не в них дело.